# Angular injected service's behaviour can be modified. How could one create a service and be sure its behaviour is read only

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Javascript is a functional programming language. In angular js, when the injector inject a service singleton in a controller or another service for example, you can replace any public method of the object by another method. Example :

```
 angular.module('App')
        .component('Header', {
          templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
          controller: ['UserService', function (UserService) {
          /*Here we change the behavior and any other controller using the login method will be broke and it will be hard to find why especially in a group work environnement */
     UserService.login = function () {   /* Do nothing*/      };
}]
});
```

Is there a way to prevent this ? Or am I missing something important about the javascript way of dealing with contracts.

Comment: See [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) maybe, but you should not rely on client-side code for security.

Comment: Libraries like jquery, lodash, etc. do not care about this. Why you should?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos thanks, this should do the work. Is it a common pattern ? I mean should a developer always make his service read-only or trust the other service/controller that are using his service although that is it not safe because the console won't even output an error and you have no way to find where in the code the service has been muted. ( And yes I have sever side verification, the login method is just for an example ) Thanks again.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov So I guess it is not a common pattern.

Comment: I would say it's not a common pattern. I've never used it, for example. I would think a team of developers could all agree that overriding methods from a service is bad practice and not do it. Plus doing so is likely to break the service, so why use a service you only intend to break? Basically, this isn't something I would worry about.

Comment: This is not used every day but not sure why. Maybe people did not consider it because their understanding of the language/ecosystem was not sufficient (or any other reason). In the present however, immutability is gaining a lot of attention (and not only in Javascript). There are many JS libraries to support immutable models ([immutable-js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), [baobab](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab), and the [most famous](http://redux.js.org/)), but `Object.freeze()` is a cheap (and in any case appropriate) way of achieving the effect.